# run second script in a new terminal window

Tags: terminal, script

I have two scripts;  script_1 and script_2, the latter must receive 2 parameters.  Before finishing script_1 I want it to call and execute script_2 in a new terminal window and pass it the 2 parameters it needs.  how could i do it?